# Got scammed by a "Sugar Daddy", looking for advice on what to do now?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I know how it sounds and I feel like a total fool for falling for it. I wish I had done my research before I followed thru with it, but now I don't know what to do from here. I've been talking to someone thru a website for a couple months now and they had offered to send me money before but I was always unsure so I never accepted. I finally decided to trust them and needed a little help with bills and taking my car to the shop for repairs.

When they told me they needed my bank login information I was super hesitant but ultimately gave in because I only had $50 in my account and figured what was the worst that would happen, I'd be out $50 or I'd be up $200. Well the check they deposited ended up being for $5100. Which was insane and blew my mind. I didn't even expect it to go thru, figured it was a mistake. He explained that there had been a mix up with his financial adviser and the money that I was sent was supposed to go to a charity and that he would need me to send that out once the check cleared.

It sounded suspicious and I wish I had trusted my gut but I stupidly waited a couple days, saw the money was in my account and let him know. He wanted me to send it thru CashApp but I told him I didn't have access to that and asked what other ways I could send it for him. We agreed on a money order mailed to an address in the same state he was supposedly from, so I went down to the bank, pulled out the $5100 and went out and got a money order from a local place by me for $4900. Sent it that afternoon, and told him it was in the mail. I hadn't heard back from him after this for a couple days and assumed it was something to do with his mom (whom he told me was in the hospital) so I didn't immediately suspect anything.

I went to message him last night and saw he had blocked me/deleted his account and all the messages were gone. Now my bank is $5100 in the negative, and I've not spoken with my bank yet. I'm honestly scared I'm going to get in trouble and I'm not wanting my family to find out about this at all. I don't want to file a police report or anything like that either if I don't have to. I didn't screenshot anything and I can't remember the address he asked me to send the money too, I don't even have the receipt for the money order to prove that I don't have the cash still. I am absolutely unsure what to do. Going to be contacting my bank tomorrow morning but would love some advice for what to say to them, how to proceed with all of this. Thanks you!!

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, **make sure you close your bank account and open a new one!** Consider your current account compromised.

Comment: "would love some advice for what to say to them, how to proceed with all of this." Confess **everything** to the bank **and the police**.  Honestly, Law.SE is a better place to ask about this.

Comment: I agree with @RonJohn, but before going to the police, I'd speak to a lawyer.  He/she can advise you regarding the process and how best to approach it without inadvertently admitting to something more serious than you actually did.